# How and why a host can have multiple netbios names?

Tags: netbios

As per article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS, section 'NetBIOS name vs Internet host name' says

```
When NetBIOS is run in conjunction with Internet protocols (e.g., NBT), each computer may have multiple names: one or more NetBIOS name service names and one or more Internet host names.
```

I cannot understand how can a computer can have multiple NetBIOS (NBT) names and why would it have ?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft added the feature of multiple NetBIOS names in Windows 2000/2003 servers.
Some example scenarios why this would be useful:

- Recover a dead file server data from backup onto another working server and
  continue providing published shares to the users that are using the name
  of the dead server as well as users that use the existing name
- Consolidating multiple file servers into one server
- When acquiring a company, to transfer file server data to own server and
  share it using the same name and the same URL.

Additional NetBIOS names are specified in registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters`
by adding a REG_SZ value named `OptionalNames`.

If this is not working, you might need under the same registry key to
add a REG_DWORD registry value named `DisableStrictNameChecking` with the value of `1`.

For more information see the article
[Multiple Server Names on Windows](https://dimitri.janczak.net/2016/09/26/multiple-server-names-on-windows/).